# Get Error from the same value added on the table php

Tags: php

Hello every one this is simple problem. I am working on a PHP project reserve subject of student. When I click the subject from another table it display to other table dynamically,the problem is how to get the error with the same value that added on the table?

here is the code subject:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblsubjecschedule ORDER BY Subject");

$i=0;
$b =1;
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) ){


echo "<tr><td>".$row['Subject']."<input type='hidden' name='subj[$i]' value=".$row['Subject']."></td>
<td>".$row['Lec']."<br/>".$row['Lab']."<input type='hidden' name='leclab[$i]' value=".$row['Lec']."><input type='hidden' name='lab[$i]' value=".$row['Lab']."></td>

<td>".$row['Descriptive']."<input type='hidden' name='desc[$i]' value=".$row['Descriptive']."></td>
<td>".$row['Day']."<br/>".$row['Labday']."<input type='hidden' name='daylabday[$i]' value=".$row['Day']."><input type='hidden' name='labday[$i]' value=".$row['Labday']."></td>

<td>".$row['LecTime']."<br/>".$row['LabTime']."<input type='hidden' name='lectlabt[$i]' value=".$row['LecTime']."><input type='hidden' name='labtime[$i]' value=".$row['LabTime']."></td>

<td>".$row['Room']."<br/>".$row['Labroom']."<input type='hidden' name='roomlabroom[$i]' value=".$row['Room']."><input type='hidden' name='labroom[$i]' value=".$row['Labroom']."></td>

<td><input id='send' name='reserv[$i]' type='submit' value='Add' onclick='addRow('myTable')' /> </td></tr>";

$i++;


}
  if (isset($_POST['reserv'])){
 if(!empty($_POST['reserv'])){
         $a = current(array_keys($_POST['reserv']));
  $subj=$_POST['subj'][$a];
 $leclab=$_POST['leclab'][$a];
 $lab=$_POST['lab'][$a];
 $labday=$_POST['labday'][$a];
 $desc=$_POST['desc'][$a];
 $daylab=$_POST['daylabday'][$a];
 $lectlabt=$_POST['lectlabt'][$a];
 $labtime=$_POST['labtime'][$a];
 $roomLabroom=$_POST['roomlabroom'][$a];
 $labroom=$_POST['labroom'][$a];



    }
    }


?>
```

and here is the code that display the subject added:

```
<table border="1" id="myTable" style='width: 900px;'>

<thead>
<tr>
    <th>SubjectCode <th>Units <th>Time <th>Day <th>Room</th> 
</tr>
</thead>

 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['reserv'])){
         $_SESSION["S[]"]=array();
                $_SESSION["lec[]"]=array();
                $_SESSION["lab[]"]=array();
                $_SESSION["Day[]"]=array();
            $_SESSION["lday[]"]=array();
            $_SESSION["lect[]"]=array();
                $_SESSION["labt[]"]=array();
            $_SESSION["room[]"]=array();
            $_SESSION["lroom[]"]=array();
                if (isset($_SESSION["counter"])){
                    $_SESSION["counter"]=$_SESSION["counter"]+1;
                    $counter=$_SESSION["counter"];
                }else{$_SESSION["counter"]=0;
                    $counter=$_SESSION["counter"];
                }

                    $counter=$_SESSION["counter"];


                            $_SESSION["S['$counter']"]=$subj;
                         $_SESSION["lec['$counter']"]=$leclab;
                         $_SESSION["lab['$counter']"]=$lab;
                         $_SESSION["Day['$counter']"]=$daylab;
                          $_SESSION["lday['$counter']"]=$labday;
                         $_SESSION["lect['$counter']"]=$lectlabt;
                         $_SESSION["labt['$counter']"]=$labtime;
                         $_SESSION["room['$counter']"]=$roomLabroom;
                         $_SESSION["lroom['$counter']"]=$labroom;




            $c=0;
            while($c<=$counter){
                if($_SESSION["S['$c']"]==""){echo "-";}

            echo "<tr><td>".$_SESSION["S['$c']"] . "</td>
            <td>".$_SESSION["lec['$c']"] . "<br/>".$_SESSION["lab['$c']"] . "</td>
            <td>".$_SESSION["lect['$c']"] . "<br/>".$_SESSION["labt['$c']"] . "</td>
            <td>".$_SESSION["Day['$c']"] . "<br/>".$_SESSION["lday['$c']"] . "</td>
            <td>".$_SESSION["room['$c']"] . "<br/>".$_SESSION["lroom['$c']"] . "</td></tr><br>";
                 $unit=$_SESSION["lec['$c']"] + $_SESSION["lab['$c']"];
            $c=$c+1;

              $units= $units+$unit;
            }


        }


 echo"<input id='send' name='reset' type='submit' value='reset' />";
    if(isset($_POST['reset'])){
            unset($_SESSION['name']);
            unset($_SESSION['counter']);
            unset($_SESSION[$_SESSION['counter']]);

        }

 ?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What error? Posting a wall of badly formatted code and expecting us to pick out some random error is NOT going to get your question answered.

Comment: What i mean is when i add value1 to other table and add another value1 to the same table the error prompt or color the the same value that has been added

Answer (score 0):

You can add `unique` index to control your field uniqueness value, and use `insert ignore` which would NOT insert value if exact value exists... And you can check if value was inserted with affected rows.

That's my answer if I understood you correctly.

Comment: sorry sir i cant really understand i am new in this php can you explain it with the code ? if thats ok?

Comment: you should start from [mysql insert syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html)

Comment: but i don't want to save the data first i need to add in the table row and get the error when the same value added on the table not on the database!